# How to access dropdown in static method

Tags: c#

I have taken a `DropDownList` in my `home.aspx`  and in `home.aspx.cs` page I want to access it within a static method. How it possible? I can't access it in static method. Please help me..

Answer (score 4):

No it isn't possible.

This is a fundamental rule of many languages. Static methods cannot access anything that is instance-specific. An *instance* of a `DropDownList` on an ASP.NET is exactly that.. an *instance* variable. A *static* method is across all instances.

To get what you want.. you need to pass an instance into it. Something like this:

```
public class ObjectA {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static string GetName(ObjectA instance) {
        return instance.Name;
    }
}
```

(Yes, that's a horrible example.. )

So, with an ASP.NET page.. you might do something like this:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    doSomethingWith(dropDownList1);
}

public static void doSomethingWith(DropDownList dropDown) {
    // use the dropdown variable here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `DropDownList` as a parameter of your static method, then you could call the method of this instance from your static.